# UITabBar setBackgroundImage not working

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm trying to customize a tabbar and i use the following code to change the background.

```
UIImage *TabBarControllerBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ios7TabBarBackground"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:TabBarControllerBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e868a80'

Why is this? It works perfect to change my navigationbar like this.

Comment: do you want to change the tabbar tint color?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look closer at that error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e868a80'
```

What it's telling you is that UIAppearance doesn't implement the `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` selector.

You'll need to drop the last argument - apparently UIAppearance doesn't like it. Turn it into this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:TabBarControllerBackground];
```